# Mock a call function to an external module

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class that does some validates on a pandas dataframe I read.
The class looks something like this (simplified some stuff might make no sense)

```
import pandas as pd

class PandasValidator:
    read_kwargs = {'sep'='\t',header=None}
    def __init__(self,path_to_data:str,max_rows:int) -> None:
        self.path = path

def validate_num_rows(self,threshold: float = 0.1) -> bool:
    df_shape = pd.read_csv(self.path,*self.read_kwargs).shape
    return df_shape[0]*threshold <= self.max_rows
```

I want to test the method validate_num_rows, so I would like to patch the first line of the function, I don't to read an actual df when testing it, my test would look something like this (this is not working code, my best attempt).

```
@patch('df.read_csv') #not sure what goes in here
def test_validate_num_rows(mock) -> None:
    mock.shape=(30,30)
    result = PandasValidator('dummy-path',30).validate_num_rows(0.1)
    assert result == True
```

To be honest I have no idea what to patch and mock or how to do it. I want to mock the first line of the validate_num_rows method. I know refactoring the code would make testing easier but that's not a choice I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class would be easier to test if it accepted a dataframe instead of reading it itself.

```py
import pandas as pd

class PandasValidator:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame, max_rows: int) -> None:
        self._df = df
        self._max_rows = max_rows

    def validate_num_rows(self, threshold: float = 0.1) -> bool:
        return self._df.shape * threshold <= self._max_rows
```

Now in your test, you just need to construct a dataframe in memory and pass it to `PandasValidator`.

Then you can make another function that reads a dataframe from a file:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def read_csv(path: Path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', header=None)
```

If you want to test this function, you can use the [`monkeypatch` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html) from `pytest`:

```py
import pandas
import your_module


def test_read_csv(monkeypatch):
    expected_dataframe = # create a dataframe somehow

    def fake_read_csv(path, **kwargs):
        assert path == Path('/foo/bar')
        assert kwargs == {'sep': '\t', 'header': None}
        return expected_dataframe

    monkeypatch.setattr(pandas, "read_csv", fake_read_csv)

    actual_dataframe = your_module.read_csv(Path('/foo/bar'))
    assert actual_dataframe == expected_dataframe
```

Another approach is to not use monkeypatching at all, but to test the function against the real file system using [temporary files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import your_module

def test_read_csv(tmp_dir: Path):
    csv_path = tmp_dir / "my_fake_csv.csv"
    csv_path.write_text(some_predefined_csv)
    dataframe = your_module.read_csv(csv_path)
    # TODO: assert some properties about your dataframe
```

Some people would characterize it as an integration test, not a unit test, because it talks to the real file system. Perhaps it's more suitable for this function because it doesn't do much except talk to the file system. Also see ["Stop Using Mocks (for a while)" by Harry Percival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk-f3B-eMkI)

Comment: thanks a lot, but why the test_get_ssh? Also do I need two nested fucntions? Thanks

Comment: 1. I copypasted some piece of code incorrectly, fixed; 2. It doesn't need to be a nested function, but other tests make no use of it, so I don't see why put it on the top level. 3. There are other tools like [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) that let you use a mock (what I proposed is [not a mock but a fake/stub](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)).

Comment: Thanks!  I am looking more for a mock or patch

Comment: Well, it is using monkeypatching, but with a fake instead of a mock. "Patching" or "monkeypatching" meaning swapping a function in a real module or obejct with your own testing object. A "fake" or "stub" is a simplified version of the real thing (for example, a function that returns a predefined value, or a value based on a testing mapping, like `{alice -> 100, bob -> 200}`). A "mock" ("mock object") lets you assert things about its interactions, for example: "assert that my method `foo` was called twice with the argument 42". I think in this case a stub is suitable.